# De un cuadro de texto

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Me gustaría saber cómo hacer que desde un contenido de un cuadro de texto guardarlo(formulario web) como texto plano o en. Formato `JSON`

Comment: Actualmente esta pregunta incluye múltiples preguntas en una. Debería centrarse en un solo problema.

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera obtienes los datos de un form y los conviertes en json:

```js
function onSubmit( form ){
  var data = JSON.stringify( $(form).serializeArray() );
  
  console.log( data );
  return false; 
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit='return onSubmit(this)'>
  <input name='nombre' placeholder='nombre'>
  <input name='password' type='password' placeholder='password'><br>
  <button type='submit'>Convertir a json</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```